# Calling image picker intent from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using this [tutorial](http://javatechig.com/android/writing-image-picker-using-intent-in-android/) to invoke the image picker intent, however, the button that invokes the intent is inside a fragment and the code from the tutorial is not working (the intent is not called).

I need to open the intent and refresh a listview after the user picks an image. These controls are all inside the fragment.

How can I do this without having to split this code between the fragment and the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the proper way to do this is create a callback to the activity where the method sends the intent to start the imagepicker then in your `onActivityResult` of your activity you send a message back to the fragment (via a public method in the fragment class) to refresh the listview.

see [Communicating with an activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

actually looking at the tutorial the intent is wrong. it should be

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i,1);
```

Comment: Here is my code https://gist.github.com/julianonunes/00f41596e182a6a99baf . It still does not work (no action is executed when I press the button).

Answer (score 0):

have you added this to your manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```